# Not able to get the current hour on php

Tags: php, hour

I'm getting crazy, cause I'm not able to get the current hour of my system, on php page.

I have the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$hora_atual = date("G");
```

This always give me one hour earlier. How can I get the current hour?
I've tried to change the code to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$hora_atual = gmdate("G");
```

But get the same result: One hour earlier from the current time.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: <?php echo date('H'); ?>

Comment: Try `<?php echo date('G:i:s'); ?>` and see actual time maybe its just minutes difference... :)

Comment: OGM!! Thanks Tismon, after a headache I realize that my code has an include() that has the same variable... Thanks for your help.